# Highcharts: overlapped columns in exported chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export, png

The live chart looks fine, however, when exported to PNG, JPEG or PDF, the columns overlap.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/strawberry/1s27pjed/

---

```
exporting:{
                chartOptions:{
                    legend:{
                        enabled:true,
                        style: {fontFamily: "Arial"}
                    },

                }
            },
```

In addition, is there an option to change the font and size of the legend text in the export? I was able to change the title and axis fonts, but not the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`legend.style`** option is **Deprecated** in new versions and maybe that's why it doesn't work. You can use **`legend.itemStyle`** instead:

```
legend: {
    enabled:true,
    itemStyle: {fontFamily: "Arial", fontSize: '8px'}
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1s27pjed/1/).

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the legend! 

I assume the issue with the column overlap should be looked at by the developers themselves.